# Deployed heroku postgrest + database keeps crashing

Tags: postgresql, heroku, postgrest

I am trying to deploy postgrest v 0.4.2.0 app (https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest/releases/tag/v0.4.2.0) on heroku according to this instruction:

https://postgrest.com/en/v3.2/admin_deployment.html#heroku  (it's an older version, but viable in general instructions)

I already have a deployed database (via Heroku Postgres) with 1 table on my heroku account, so I keep trying to connect my DB with postgrest:

DB_URL: postgres://mpdwpnlqhwsosk:5abeb772ff431ef99e975be287970c3412174b331926b189d6485277f41d65d1@ec2-174-129-224-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/da5a8m1p77diab

And so, my app is just crashing (H10 error). I can't see table, etc. Although, I can successfully connect to this DB via pgAdmin

Is there I am doing something wrong, or is that some kind of nasty bug?

Logs:
2017-06-19T09:53:52.579013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-06-19T09:53:52.568134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-06-19T10:38:45.049215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2017-06-19T10:38:45.838847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `./env-to-config ./postgrest postgrest.conf`

2017-06-19T10:38:47.811334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-06-19T10:38:47.752947+00:00 app[web.1]: ConfigError {configErrorLocation = Key "" "secret-is-base64", configConversionError = Just [ConversionError {conversionErrorLoc = "boolValue", conversionErrorWhy = TypeError, conversionErrorVal = Just (String "false"), conversionErrorType = Just Bool, conversionErrorMsg = Nothing}]}

2017-06-19T10:38:47.822918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2017-06-19T11:04:22.519115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-mesa-95349.herokuapp.com request_id=7f7c6d70-c23b-400a-aec8-83758cb226cf fwd="109.184.214.45" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: This is not your database crashing. [H10 errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed) indicate that the process (`web` in this case) has crashed. Try tailing your logs (`heroku logs --tail`) and then restart the app (`heroku restart`) then you should see the error which is causing the application to crash.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, this probably should not have been downvoted. It looks like a manifestation of a bug that was recently fixed in https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest/pull/897

The fix is not yet part of a release, but will be in the next release.